# Is there any built in function to render image file extension like jpg, png etc?

Tags: 7, media

Is there any built in function in Drupal 7 to render image file extension like jpg, png etc on node load.

I have tried image_get_info etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`image_get_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_get_info/7) should do the trick.

```
//if you want to get the extension of image1.jpg
$filepath = "sites/default/files/images/image1.jpg";
$info_var = image_get_info($filepath, FALSE);
echo "the image extension is ".$info_var['extension'];
```